# Showing a set is a Borel set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

I have the following setup: denote $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{A_1 \times A_2: A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{B}\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> If $S \in \mathcal{M}$, then we want to show that $\{x: (x, c+x) \in S\}$ is in $\mathcal{B}$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've observed that $\mathcal{M}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the product $\sigma$-algebra for $\lambda \times \lambda$. I only see that $\{x: (x, c+x) \in S\}$ represents the $x$-values for which the lines $y=x+c$ intersects $S$. However, I don't know to where to go from here to show that it is Borel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea with most of these exercises is two notice that the sets in question are defined by some equations from which you can build a function.

In that sense consider the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2,\ x\mapsto (x,x+c)$. This function is clearly continuous as it is component-wise continuous.

Now, as with open sets, Borel sets are sent back to Borel sets by continuous functions. This is, if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then if $B\subseteq Y$ is Borel, then $f^{-1}[B]\subseteq X$ is Borel.

Your set is precisely the inverse image of $S$:

$$f^{-1}[S]=\{x:\ f(x)\in S\}=\{x:\ (x,x+c)\in S\}.$$

So as $S$ is a Borel set, then $f^{-1}[S]$ is also a Borel set.